# Debug memory wrapping code from Writing Solid Code, or similar alternatives for C/C++ available to download?

Tags: c++, c

I'm reading "Writing Solid Code" and like the stuff about wrapping the memory functions to help catch bugs and track memory leaks etc. Its all provided in appendix B but there's a lot to type in. Does anybody know if this code is available somewhere to download?
Or if there is similar code from another source that does the same thing available somewhere to download?
I'm interested in both C and C++ versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than filling your program with debugging wrappers, I would use an existing tool for memory debugging. Valgrind is probably the best there is.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if that, or similar, tools would run on a mobile OS platform as opposed to windows/linux/mac.

Comment: In that case I would develop and test your code on a more full-featured platform...

Comment: Yes code developed for mobiles should be run and tested on emulators/simulators as well as on handsets. But running and testing debug builds of code on the actual handset in addition to release build code is also useful. And in several instances code cannot be run on a simulator if the functionality is not present - many mobile OS simulators are not fully featured, they may not support camera functionality or tilt functionality for example, some wouldn't support SMS or telephony functionality etc. etc.